# Results not correct when using diff function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using the `diff` Matlab function to get the difference between two successive values. And as shown here in this vector nz in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/px052k8rk8vv5bw/nz.mat) as shown in nz the difference between col 261 and 260 is -1342 but when I use this script the result of difference between this coloumns don't appear in the result dnz. So if anyone could advise why this is not working?
This is my attempt:

```
load('nz.mat');
dnz = diff(nz);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you type `class(nz)` you see that your data is `unit16`. And MATLAB saturates the results when dealing with integer values, i.e. since `0 - 1342` is lower than zero (the smallest value in `uint16`) it returns zero:

```
>> dnz=diff(nz);
>> dnz(260)

ans =

      0
```

If you convert it to a class that can accomodate `-1342` like `int16` you get

```
>> dnz = diff(int16(nz));
>> dnz(260)

ans =

  -1342
```

Comment: Though `int16` values will use the same amount of memory as `uint16`, converting to `int32` might be safer unless you know that your values will never exceed 16383 (~half of `intmax('int16')`) - true for this dataset, but maybe not in general. Subsequent operations could also cause overflows too. This is why Matlab usually casts integer data to doubles when doing any sort of calculation (and sometimes casts back).